# How to convert EBCDIC to UTF8 IN SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a question:How to convert EBCDIC to UTF8 IN SSIS 2012?

I need transfer data from AS400 to MS.

When I execute task, it's raise error message

> Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

How can I do for it?

[image: setting]

Answer (score 0):

Here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee251903(v=bts.10).aspx) is a list of correlating IBM and Microsoft codepages. I believe you have to find the correct Microsoft code page ID and use that in step 2 in the code page setting.